# SB Admin Laravel 5 line chart data

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Am using the [following](https://github.com/start-laravel/sb-admin-laravel-5) package. There is a chart displayed in resources/views/mcharts.blade.php. The code is the following;

```
@section ('cchart1_panel_title','Line Chart')
            @section ('cchart1_panel_body')
            @include('widgets.charts.clinechart')
            @endsection
            @include('widgets.panel', array('header'=>true, 'as'=>'cchart1'))
```

So this code refers to widgets.charts.clinechart. Looking into that file, the code is as follows:

This prints out a nice line chart:

[image: linechart]

Where does it get this date from to draw the lines. I would expect this to come from the controller, but I can't seem to find it. What is the correct way to provide the linechart with data coming from my application

Answer (score 1):

In laravel 5.4, Run the following command for install composer for create charts

```
composer require "consoletvs/charts:5.*"
```

then, add the following in your **config/app.php** file providers

```
ConsoleTVs\Charts\ChartsServiceProvider::class,
```

then, add the following in your **config/app.php** file aliases

```
'Charts' => ConsoleTVs\Charts\Facades\Charts::class,
```

then, use the following codes in your **controller** file

```
use Charts;
public function index()
{

    $chart= Charts::multi('areaspline', 'highcharts')
    ->title('My nice chart')
    ->colors(['#ff0000', '#ffffff'])
    ->labels(['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May','June', 'July'])
    ->dataset('John', [3, 4, 3, 5, 4, 10, 12])
    ->dataset('Jane',  [1, 3, 4, 3, 3, 5, 4]);

    return view('User.chart',['chart'=>$chart]);
}
```

In your blade file called **User/chart.blade.php** add the following codes

```
<head>
{!! Charts::assets() !!}
</head>
<body>
    {!! $chart->render() !!}
</body>
```

[Click here for demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOlWI.png)

Answer (score 0):

It is in javascript here https://github.com/start-laravel/sb-admin-laravel-5/blob/master/resources/js/frontend.js

You could create api with Laravel and then with ajax get that data.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't see it :-). APIs don't really fit my app now so was thinking to= create a controller that sending that data to the view. Not sure how to do this though....

Comment: well because charts get data via javascript you have to use it... you could send data with php to view but in that case you need to mix php data as array into chart javascript.. in my opinion it is better to create route with data you need and then get it with ajax